# How to get the relational sub-components using query?

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I have a table with `parent-child` in a same table.

First I run query `SELECT id, pid FROM table_relation where pid = 10`. This gives result

```
| id  | pid  |
| --- | ---- |
| 92  | 10   |
| 97  | 10   |
| 100 | 10   |
```

From the result I have make query with id = 92; 97 & 100 And again make another query with the id result.

I can achieve this result by using `loop` But this way I have make too many loops. Is there a way to acheive the result only using query ?

I tried using `UNION` but it doesn't give me correct result.

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.pid
FROM
    table_relation AS e
WHERE
    e.pid IN (select id from table_relation where pid = 10)
order by e.id ) UNION
(SELECT
    e.id,
    e.pid
FROM
    table_relation AS e
WHERE
    e.id IN (select id from table_relation where pid = 10 order by id)) order by id
```

Comment: The two queries in the union seem the same to me. There's no point in using `ORDER BY` in a subquery used with `IN()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL version 8+, there is recursive common table expression

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT id, pid
  FROM table_relation
  WHERE pid = 10
  UNION
  SELECT table_relation.id, table_relation.pid
  FROM table_relation
  JOIN cte ON cte.id = table_relation.pid
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

Comment: I have older MySQL in server